# saveInstantState() for Classes

Tags: java, android

How do you save a class in savedInstantState().

The Fragment is supposed to be a text log that can be replaced by other fragments via buttons.

The Fragment in question:

```
    package com.example.student.mysterygame;



    public class logView extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

AbsListView mListView;
EditText testField;

String mmMessage;
String name;
String date;

boolean hasEnteredPassword;

public static ArrayAdapter<LogItems> mArrayAdapter;
public static ArrayList<LogItems> mArrayList;
private MainActivity mmActivity;


public static logView newInstance() {
    logView fragment = new logView();;



    return fragment;
}

public logView() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mArrayList = new ArrayList<LogItems>();

        mArrayAdapter = new textLogAdpater(getActivity(), mArrayList);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log_view, container, false);
    //testField.setOnEditorActionListener(new onEditorDoneInteraction());


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mListView = getView().findViewById(R.id.logView);

    mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    testField = getView().findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button sendButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

    mmActivity = new MainActivity();

    name = "You";
    date = "09/05/2022";

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("Send Button", "Creating a new Log Entry.");

            mmMessage = String.valueOf(testField.getText());

            LogItems newEntry = new LogItems(name, date, mmMessage);

            mArrayAdapter.add(newEntry);
            mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            if(!hasEnteredPassword){

                if (Objects.equals(mmMessage, "Test")) {
                    //UI response is granted
                    populateLogOnStartWith("UI", "10/123/2018:", "Checking...");
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            populateLogOnStartWith("UI", "10/123/2018:", "Access Granted");
                            setFriend1Logs();
                        }
                    }, 1000);

                    hasEnteredPassword = true;

                } else {
                    populateLogOnStartWith("UI", "10/123/2018:", "checking...");
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            populateLogOnStartWith("UI", "10/123/2018:", "Access denied! Try Again");
                        }
                    }, 1000);

                    //UI response is denied

                }
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * ALL POPULATION REQUESTS FOR THE LOG SHOULD BE PUT BELOW THIS COMMENT.
     */

    Log.d("Log Population", "OnCreate called for LogPopulation");
    populateLogOnStartWith("UI", "10/11/2018:", "Connecting to Friend1 Phone....");
    populateLogOnStartWith("UI", "10/11/2018:", "Phone is now Connected");
    populateLogOnStartWith("UI", "10/123/2018:", "Enter Password to access phone:");


}

public void setFriend1Logs() {
    Log.d("Log Population", "OnCreate called for LogPopulation");
    populateLogOnStartWith("UI", "10/11/2018:", "blah blah");
    populateLogOnStartWith("UI", "10/11/2018:", "Put Story here");
    populateLogOnStartWith("UI", "10/123/2018:", "I don't know what will come next");

}

private void populateLogOnStartWith(String name, String date, String entry) {

    LogItems newEntry = new LogItems(name, date, entry);
    mArrayAdapter.add(newEntry);
    mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//---------------------------------------------Save Mechanics----------------------------------------


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);




}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) 
{

}
}
```

This class contains the three fields that I wanted for the Text Log to have.

The Class in question:

```
    package com.example.student.mysterygame;

/**
 * Created by student on 09/05/2018.
 */

public class LogItems {

//This is a Data set class. This is used to set, store and call a Data Set. in this case
//The data set contains the logName, logDate and lodEntry.

/**
 * There is no need to touch this class if you are not adding a data set. this can be ignored
 * for the most part.
 */

private String logName;
private String logDate;
private String logEntry;

public String getLogName(){return  logName;}
public String getLogDate(){return logDate;}
public String getLogEntry(){return logEntry;}

public void setLogName(String LogName){this.logName = LogName;}
public void setLogDate(String LogDate){this.logDate = LogDate;}
public void setLogEntry(String logEntry){this.logEntry = logEntry;}

public LogItems(String name, String date, String logEntry){

    this.logEntry = logEntry;
    this.logName = name;
    this.logDate = date;
}
}
```

Comment: Add the code directly into the question

Comment: sorry about that, I've only started stack over flow today. There I added in my code directly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. First Option is to make this class parcelable if you have access to it and then in the onSaveInstanceState method in your fragment add this to the savedInstanceState bundle as a parcelable

If you do not have access to this class then you will have to save all the elements of this class one by one to the savedInstanceState bundle and then restore them in the onActivityCreated method of your fragment